# Can I split emacs the window 4 ways (vertically and horizontally) in a 4 grid layout with different files in each?

Tags: window

I just started using emacs and since I have been using Sublime Text for a while, I am used to the four-grid-layout with 4 windows stacked horizontally and vertically. I have been able to split the screen horizontally only. How do I split it 4 ways?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To split the window in half with a vertical divider, use the command `split-window-right`. To split it in half with a horizontal divider, use the command `split-window-below`.

For example, assume we have this window by default:

```
.-------------.
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
'-------------'
```

`M-x split-window-right RET`:

```
.-------------.
|      |      |
|      |      |
|      |      |
|      |      |
|      |      |
'-------------'
```

`M-x split-window-below RET`:

```
.-------------.
|             |
|             |
|-------------|
|             |
|             |
'-------------'
```

`split-window-right` is bound to `C-x 3` by default. `split-window-below` is bound to `C-x 2` by default.

ErgoEmacs has [a good guide](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_winner_mode.html) on window management and navigation, including how to save a specific arrangement (e.g. a 4-way split) and load it automatically.

Comment: Thanks for that. It works. How do I jump from one window to the other without `C-X o`. Say, I want to jump to the right window to the current one, how do I do that?

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee: in general, please post a separate question rather than follow up in comments.  In this case, though, you could consider using [`windmove`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove).

Comment: @Dan thank you, I found out `windmove` in another emacs question.

Comment: The ErgoEmacs link covers that, among other things. Glad to help!

Answer (score 9):

Use the split-window-xxx commands, as described in another answer. If you always want a grid of 4 windows, here's a command you could use:

```
(defun split-4-ways ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-other-windows)
  (split-window-right)
  (split-window-below)
  (windmove-right)
  (split-window-below)
  (windmove-left))
```